# How to stop my VPS from picking up ARP reqs it is not supposed to?

Tags: debian, vps, xen, arp

*Machine: Xen-3.0 image running stable Debian Linux 2.6.18, pretty vanilla.*

My VPS provider asks me to deal with some trouble my image is causing, namely handling IP addresses it is not supposed to:

> The problem is that your server seems
>   to be configured to use IPs that have
>   not been appointed to you. Your server
>   responds to ARP requests for the IPs
>   81.171.111.219 and 81.171.111.218. But you are not allowed to use those.

Not explicitly, as far as I can tell!  At least, nothing under /etc or /var/tmp mentions these IP addresses. But `arp -v` says something I can't make sense of:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
81.171.111.1             ether   00:0C:DB:E3:80:00   C                     eth0
Entries: 1      Skipped: 0      Found: 1
```

What is it listening to?  The possibilities seem to be:

1. It's not my fault: my VPS providers have overlooked something.  What might that be?
2. 81.171.111.1 means I'm happy listening in on ARP requests that I shouldn't be: how do I change this?  In any case, what does this mean?
3. I'm looking in completely the wrong place for information on what my image is doing.  Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was, as I didn't find out for myself, the ethernet interface was bound to the forbidden IP addresses, although only the gateway address was shown using `route`/`apr`/`ip route show`.  `ip addr show` would have listed the missing addresses; using `ip addr del` on the two misconfigured ip addresses fixed the problem.

I should really learn more about Linux networking — this seems like it should have been obvious to me to check.  I found Daniel Weiss' [Proxy ARP with Linux](http://www.sjdjweis.com/linux/proxyarp/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [**arptables**](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Using_arptables_to_disable_ARP) package for debian. Possibly could setup static ARP routes. There is little reason for your box to know how to get to other boxes via ARP, you could disable it entirely.

Comment: +1: "you could disable it entirely" - that is probably true; I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at /etc/rc.local for any static entry. 
Please post the values of :

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all|grep arp
```

Make sure you get the same results from :

```
arp -na and cat /proc/net/arp
```

You may have cache poisoning going on the network. The only way to stop it is to block them at the firewall (they could only allow you to request the gateway with firewall rules). You could also do this on your side.

Alternatively, I would suggest you to monitor what is going on with Wireshark. http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Could use tcpdump if you have to use a command line interface as well.